# Unexpected image not shown in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am only able to test in IE8, FF and Chrome on my set.

This page does not show the image in IE8, but works fine in FF and Chrome.. any suggestions?

Thanks

http://skateboardingphoto.co.uk/skate-photos-june-2011/lowdown-2

Comment: Why the jQuery tag? Also, can we assume that this is the large image on the right you're talking about?

Comment: Yes, sorry - large image on the right. The site runs a lot of jQuery. Possibly not needed in this query though.. Thanks

Comment: Is it only on the first page of the site?

Comment: Seems to be the case - I can not find it happening anywhere else, that's what strikes me as 'Odd'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the file itself. There is something about it that IE doesn't like. If I download it and drag it to IE it has the same response. If I open it in a graphic program (IrfanView in my case) it works fine and if I save it as a jpg then this newly saved file works in IE.

It must be somethign to do with the image processors in the browsers with there being something in the jpg you have that makes IE bug out whereas other browsers handle it better. I'm not too familiar with jpg file structures so can't tell you exactly what is wrong but try resaving it again.

Also you probably want to do this anyway because 434KB is probably a bit big for a web image. My resaved version came in at a much more respectable 77KB and was indistinguishable from the original to my eye.

Comment: I have marked this as the answer as it seems that the image itself was somehow corrupt? I loaded it into my image editor, xported and re-loaded and now it works fine! Very odd, however that the other browsers could cope with it?

Comment: @Infocentre: Yeah, it is odd but image files are complicated things and have a lot of optional bits that image processors might not deal with, etc (see for example older version's of IE and their inability to do png transparency). It may be that this file had some optional extension that for some reason IE was unable to ignore and thus caused it to be corrupted while other stuff either understood it or were just better able to ignore it. It is very odd and I wish I wasn't too busy to investigate further into the file format.

Comment: I see. I guess i took for granted the complexities involved! I have just noticed a bunch of other incompatibilities with IE7 which need to be sorted.. new post coming up!

Answer (score 0):

This is curious, I fired up [fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and did requests in Chrome and IE.

Right enough, the image popped up in Chrome but not IE. Here is a screenshot of the fiddler trace:
[image]

No '16' is the IE request and number '17' is the Chrome request.

The [request type](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) for IE was an HTTP/206, which although part of the "HTTP/2xx" sucessful group indicates that only partial content was delivered.

The request type for Chrome was a 304 which I believe indicates the image is cached locally and has not been modified.

Without being sure, I am wondering if this is the result of some caching setting on the server.

Comment: Lot's of responses - this could be something, however. I am running Hyper Cache on WP... I am going to try re-loading the image onto the server..

Comment: I was trying to do similar but fiddler wasn't playing with my proxy nicely. Did IE really request a partial file like that? And for a proper comparison you might want to delete chrome's cached version to check if the HTTP request is the same or not (not sure if a ctrl-f5 might do the trick too).

Answer (score 0):

this link:
http://skateboardingphoto.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/NOMAD.jpg
doesnt open in IE7-8. looks like server-side error, not Jquery.